# How to extract text from text nodes within same parent node through XPath

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I am running some UI tests using Selenium in Java to pick up pieces of text from the UI to assert against for some automation testing.

I have the following elements on my UI:

```
<span id="MainContent" class="control-label">
    "Text 1"
    <br>
    "Text 2"
    <br>
    "Text 3"
</span>
```

I need to pick out each of 3 those separate pieces of text individually and assert against each one in isolation.

I'm having problem with my locator as when I run the test selenium tells me unable to locate element.

For the first text item ("Text 1") I have used the following locator code which isn't working. I've tried some other variants of this but always hitting the unable to find locator error. Help!

```
By category = By.xpath("//span[@id='MainContent'][1]");
```

Comment: just try with the xpath //span[@id='MainContent']

Comment: No luck with this @Murthi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the HTML you have provided to extract the texts e.g. **Text 1**, **Text 2** and **Text 3** you can use the following solution:

```
WebElement myElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='control-label' and @id='MainContent']"));
// to extract the text "Text 1"
String myText1 = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript('return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;', myElement).toString();
// to extract the text "Text 2"
String myText2 = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript('return arguments[0].childNodes[3].textContent;', myElement).toString();
// to extract the text "Text 3"
String myText3 = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', myElement).toString();
```

Comment: Think I'm almost there with this solution. I;ve not seen or used JavascriptExecutor before so I'm just making sure I understand it. But any ideas why I get an error of 'Too many characters in character literal' on the code return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;

Comment: @Matt Checkout my updated answer. Let me know the status

Comment: I'm trying this again but get the same error in my IDE.  'Too many characters in character literal'. InteliJ suggests converting to string lateral which replaces single quote with double quote but then it has a problem with .strip() saying cannot resolve method???

Comment: I have this working now. I had to change the String rows to be as follows: String myText1 = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;", myElement).toString(). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

There aren't technically 3 elements, there is technically one. What you could do is get the text and split it up based on the separators.

```
By category = By.xpath("//span[@id='MainContent']") ;

String allText = driver.findElement(category).getText();

String[] allTextArray = allText.split("<br>");

String text1 = allTextArray[0];
String text2 = allTextArray[1];
String text3 = allTextArray[2];
```

Comment: I worked out in the end that I could just concatenate them all together into one string and this would allow me to compare to the database value which I handled in the same way i.e. a concatenation. All good now as it works. Thanks for your option as well. I'm sure I will be referring back to this at some point in the future.